# Splitting ajax return value

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I think what I'm trying to do is pretty simple, but I'm stuck.  I'm trying to split the returned value of my ajax function.  I don't think I'm correctly specifying the return value to split.  Code is below.

```
 <script>
 function showCars(){
   var name = document.getElementById(“carID”).value;

   $.ajax({
        url : "<%=context%>/ListCarServlet?name=" + name,
        type : "POST",
        async : false,
        success : function(data) {
                 String[2] a = data.split("|");   //<———don’t think i’m splitting return value correctly
                document.getElementById(“value1”).value = a[0];
                document.getElementById(“value2”).value = a[1];         
        }
   });
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: `String[2] a` isn't JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write `String[2]` because that isn't valid JavaScript syntax. Instead you could write `var a = data.split("|");`. You can [read more about variable declarations using `var` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

For example:

```js
var data = "foo|bar";
var a = data.split("|");
console.log(a[0]); // "foo"
console.log(a[1]); // "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
   var fields = data.split("|");
```

and access like this

fieds[0],fields[1],......